# Знаки препинания. Нужна помощь

Tags: пунктуация

Буду благодарен, если разберете 1ое предложение.
*В ответах написано 4,5.
1) Меня съедало любопытство __ почему старик не хочет ехать в Москву?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) **Меня съедало любопытство: почему старик не хочет ехать в Москву?**

Предложение 1 может быт оформлено как СПП (запятая)  или БСП (двоеточие). Но так как в конце стоит **знак вопроса**, то это БСП (двоеточие).

Но в данном случае вторая часть **поясняет или изъясняет** первую (объясняет, что именно вызывало любопытство),  а не называет причину, поэтому этот вариант не подходит.

(Как это проверить?  **Здесь невозможна замена БСП на  СПП со значением причины:** Меня съедало любопытство, так как старик не хотел ехать в Москву).

Сравнить: Сверлила мысль: почему она не пошла переодеться? [Знаки препинания в бессоюзном сложном предложении | orthographia.ru](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135)

2)  А вот в предложениях 4 и 5 вторая часть действительно обозначает причину того, о чем говорится в первой части.

**3) Дополнение (о постановке вопросительного знака)**
http://techwriters.ru/news/biblioteka/rozental.html

Примечание. Если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения образует косвенный вопрос, то в конце предложения **вопросительный знак обычно не ставится:** Я прервал речь Савельина вопросом, сколько у меня всего денег (П.); Корчагин неоднократно спрашивал меня, когда он может выписаться (Н.О.).

Однако если косвенный вопрос содержит **сильно выраженную вопросительную** интонацию, в конце сложноподчиненного предложения вопросительный знак ставится: Скажите, пожалуйста, что это за огни? (Л.Т.); Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником? (М.Г.)

В то же время отметим, что в этих случаях опорным словом является **глагол**, а не существительное. Поэтому в предложении 1 лучше поставить двоеточие и считать его БСП.

Answer (score 1):

Меня съедало любопытство, почему старик не хочет ехать в Москву?
Это сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным изъяснительным.
Придаточное изъяснительное, потому что вопрос, который задаём к этой части предложения, падежный и задаём его от глагола: Меня съедало любопытство (съедало любопытство из-за чего?), почему старик не хочет ехать в Москву?

"Почему" в данном предложении - союзное слово, потому что его можно заметить другим союзным словом, например, отчего: Меня съедало любопытство, отчего старик не хочет ехать в Москву?

Схема предложения: [  х  ],(почему    ).

Comment: Вы верно определили изъяснительное значение второй части предложения. Но что вы скажете про вопросительный знак, который, по Розенталю, в СПП обычно не ставится?

Comment: Возможно, что придаточное содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию, поэтому вопрос ставится. Но скорее всего, это можно списать на ошибку составителя.

Comment: Тогда все БСП с прямым вопросом нужно считать ошибочными. Здесь автор делает выбор: БСП с двоеточием - это выделение паузой и вопросительная интонация, СПП - нет ни паузы, ни вопросительной интонации. Сравнить: Мне было любопытно, почему старик не хочет ехать в Москву. Меня съедало любопытство: почему старик не хочет ехать в Москву? Совершенно разная интонация, разная выделительная способность изъяснительной части. Второй вариант в большей степени характерен для опорных существительных, а первый - для опорных глаголов.

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно, что значит "разобрать". Ответы даны правильные, в первом предложении сложноподчиненная связь (союзное слово *почему*):

> Меня съедало любопытство, почему старик не хочет ехать в Москву.

*(Обратите внимание, что здесь не стоит знак вопроса.)*

Ну можно представить себе ситуацию с двоеточием, но в любом случае под критерии, описанные в задании, предложение не попадает. Здесь дается
разъяснение или раскрытие содержания того, о чём говорится в первом предложении:

> Меня съедало любопытство: почему старик не хочет ехать в Москву?

Comment: Ответы даны правильные, это да. Не уверен, какой знак должен стоять в первом предложении, но в любом случае вторая часть НЕ называет причину или основание того, о чем говорится в первой части

Comment: Вот только еще одно сомнение: "почему" - союз или союзное слово?

Comment: @М_Г посмотрел в справочнике, там это союзное слово. Я соглашусь, но мне не понятно, в какой функции оно выступает как член предложения (поэтому я и выделил его сначала как союз).

Answer (score 0):

Почему - здесь союз (ну или "союзное слово"). В союзных СП двоеточие не ставится. 
"Разбор" здесь ни при чем.

PS
Зря Aer свой ответ удалил.

Comment: Да я как-то упустил, что там вопросительный знак стоит. С ним ссп как-то не вяжется, имхо, и действительно бессоюзная получается. Или вы меня поправите?

Comment: @Aer Да хоть с вопросительным, хоть без него - не получается тут CCП.