# Могут ли в бессоюзном сложном предложении использоваться союзы и союзные слова?

Tags: грамматика

В грамматике БСП определяется как сложное предложение, части которых соединяются без помощи союзов и союзных слов. В то же время у Розенталя есть тема "прямой вопрос в БСП", где во второй части присутствуют вопросительные слова.

[XXX. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В БЕССОЮЗНОМ СЛОЖНОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ | evartist.narod.ru](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/51.htm)

> Двоеточие ставится, если вторая часть представляет собой **прямой
>   вопрос**, например: Одного только я не понимаю: **как** она могла тебя
>   укусить? (Чехов);  Я ехала сейчас, говорила с вами и все думала:
>   **почему** они не стреляют?

(Симонов).

Обратим внимание на знак вопроса в конце предложения.

Вопрос: Из этого следует, что вопросительные слова в БСП выступают в своей прямой функции (то есть оформляют вопросительное предложение во второй части), но при этом ни союзами, ни союзными словами не являются?

Примечание. Эта тема звучала в вопросе [Знаки препинания. Нужна помощь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429367/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C)

Comment: Мне вот еще интересно, почему *почему* вдруг "наречное союзное слово". Что в нем знаменательного?

Comment: Aer, не могу понять, в каком тексте встречается "наречное союзное слово"

Comment: Не могу понять, *почему* дед не поехал.

Comment: как они могут не являться союзами, если они союзы? нельзя сказать проще - они не выполняют связующую роль между частями предложения? их функция - интонационно-смысловая. не соединительная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например:

почему
1. мест. нареч., вопрос по какой причине, из-за чего ◆ - Почему тебя не было слышно? — Не знаю, почему.
2. союз по каковой причине ◆ Они чувствовали свою правоту, почему и не боялись.

Эти слова могут выполнять роль союза, а могут - наречия. В вопросах они выполняют роль наречия, так что формально БСП с прямым вопросом действительно союзов не содержит.